# Python regex to replace a specifc filename (not the extension) within a command line

Tags: python, string

I have a string in a format as mentioned below in two examples:

Example 1:

```
"abc -A -mno r -input file1.tcl -aberror SVRNDF -nowarn PQRST -nowarn PRUASZ   -nolog  -sv_lib lib.so"
```

Example 2:

```
"xyz -B -ucli -i file2.tcl -pq_error"
```

I want the output as below:

Output 1:

```
"abc -A -mno r -input file1_additional_text.tcl -aberror SVRNDF -nowarn PQRST -nowarn PRUASZ   -nolog  -sv_lib lib.so"
```

Output 2:

```
"xyz -B -ucli -i file2_additional_text.tcl -pq_error"
```

I have written a small script but want to check if this can be achieved with regex and more efficiently

```
string = "abc -A -mno r -input file1.tcl -aberror SVRNDF -nowarn PQRST -nowarn PRUASZ   -nolog  -sv_lib lib.so"
slist = string.split(" ")
new_s = []
for i in slist:
    if i.endswith('.tcl'):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(i)
        traces_filename = "{filename}_additional_text{file_extension}".format(filename=filename, file_extension=file_extension)
        i = traces_filename
    new_s.append(i)
new_string = ' '.join(new_s)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make a pattern to detect `.tcl` files and use a capture group to change its name:

```py
import re

s = "xyz -B -ucli -i file2.tcl -pq_error"

print(re.sub(r'\b(\S+)\.tcl\b', r'\g<1>_more_text.tcl', s))
```

Gives:

```
xyz -B -ucli -i file2_more_text.tcl -pq_error
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nGHjMT/3)

Comment: Will produce a wrong result if there are embedded spaces/escaping/quoting in the command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Raw regexes aren't the best thing to transform command lines -- since there can be embedded spaces, quoting and escaping anywhere which are very hard to handle reliably with regexes.

Instead,

- parse the command line into an array of arguments as the program-to-be-run would see them (that would undo any quoting and escaping)

  - note that this process is shell-specific. Python's [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html?highlight=shlex#module-shlex) module uses POSIX shells' rules by default
- transform the arguments as needed
- combine the result back into a command line if needed (if you need to run the result in the same program, it's typically more convenient to rather pass the array to a corresponding system call directly).

---

To manipulate file names and paths, use `os.path` functions.

---

```
import shlex, os.path
argv=shlex.split(cmdline)

i = argv.index('-input')    #raises ValueError if not found, signaling that the input is invalid

fname, ext = os.path.splitext(argv[i+1])
argv[i+1] = fname + "_additional_text" + ext

cmdline = shlex.join(argv)
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you simply use replace?

```
s = "xrun -R -top r -input xmsim.tcl -xmerror SVRNDF -nowarn PRPASZ -nowarn PRUASZ   -nolog  -sv_lib libPdumpPlayerBusStim.so"
    
new_string = s.replace('.tcl', '_with_traces.tcl')

print(new_string)
```

Comment: it did work! Thanks! Was just looking for a regex way.

Comment: Will produce a wrong result if there also happens to be "`.tcl`" elsewhere.